# How javascript select remote-data.service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I bought an app. I'm new with Javascript and AngularJS. I'm trying to following the code but I don't understand how the function on homeService.js knows that has to use remote-data.service.js

This is the **home.controller.js**

```
...
(function activate() {
        ...
        loadCategories();
        ...
    })();
...
// ...............................
function loadCategories() {
        debugger;
        homeService.getFeaturedCategories()
            .then(function(categories) {
                vm.categories = categories;
            });
    }
```

The function call homeService.getFeaturedCategories(). So....

**home.service.js**

```
function getFeaturedCategories() {
        return dataService.getFeaturedCategories();
    }
```

The function call to dataService.getFeaturedCategories()
Here is when **data.service.js** call to a remoteDataService.js and this file make the hhtp.get (I paste the full code of data.service.js):

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('restaurant.common')
    .factory('dataService', dataService);

dataService.$inject = ['ENV', '$injector'];

/* @ngInject */
function dataService(ENV, $injector) {
    switch(ENV.dataProvider) {
        case 'LOCAL':
            return $injector.get('localDataService');
        case 'REMOTE':
            return $injector.get('remoteDataService');
        case 'FIREBASE':
            return $injector.get('firebaseDataService');
    }

    throw new Error('Data provider is not valid');
}
})();
```

I wanna know:

- How the function returns remoteDataService.
- Also I wanna know how make that only the function  **dataService.getFeaturedCategories()** in the home.service.js make that dataservice return a localDataService. Because I wanna load a local JSON (not make a http.get)

Thanks!

Comment: 'ENV' is working like a provider and it is set to remote some where in the config function in the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't understand question. Your data service read ENV.dataProvider once, and return proper service. It's unable to return different services for different calls in current implementation.
2. you should use "localDataService" in home.service instead of "dataService". Just change names.

In your Home.service you should have lines like:

```
homeService.$inject = ['dataService'];

function homeService(dataService){
  ...
}
```

change it to: (order of $inject and arguments should be same.)

```
homeService.$inject = ['dataService', 'localDataService'];

function homeService(dataService, localDataService){ 
  ...
}
```

and use localDataService in your fn.

Comment: No, because i want to use localDataService only with this function. How can I do that?

Comment: In home service you could request via angular $inject mechanism both dataService and localDataService, and use localDataService in one function and dataService in others

Comment: Could yo tell me the few lines that I have to put?sorry,Im too new with angular. Thanks.

Comment: I changed what you said, still working with remote data service

Comment: Also..  always match with case 'FIREBASE'

Comment: I know whats going on here

Comment: how can I change the function: function dataService(ENV, $injector) for pass by parameter "localDataService" or "remoteDataService" and return the the data? Because in configuration.js I have: dataProvider:'FIREBASE. So... no matter what i sending by the parameter always match with firebase

Comment: in your home.service you should use localDataService in function getFeaturedCategories() {
        return localDataService.getFeaturedCategories();
}